# Visual Studio Code does not track React Problems

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

I can't seem to tell Visual Studio Code to track problems in a Typescript React App. I did the following to reproduce:

```
yarn create react-app --template typescript test
code test
```

I've added the following to App.tsx:

```
public class Dummy {
    public constructor() {
        let x = 0;
    }
}
```

When I run `npm start`, I get two warnings in the console, but the Problems pane remains empty. Introducing an error (`let x = abc`) shows a problem while the file is open, but not when it's closed (although it is shown in the terminal).

I've tried using the `$eslint-stylish` matcher, as well as the problem matcher [here](https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript/issues/289).

Comment: Could you post what version of TypeScript you're using? it's in the bottom right corner (when you view a ts file)

Comment: VS Code says "Typescript React 3.7.3"

Answer (score 0):

Your issue looks like [issue 12073](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/12073) (Errors from run npm script are not showed in 'Problems' pane)
It refers to [vscode issue 1777](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/1777#issuecomment-314684785) which states:

> Looks like this went live with 1.14 (June 2017 update).
>   I actually came here looking to tone auto-detection down a bit -- it's detecting all my pre/post tasks as well as the ones I actually want to run. It looks like it selects "configured" tasks first, so this isn't a huge issue, but it'd be nice to be able to hide some NPM tasks completely (and/or not show pre/post tasks in the first place).
>   ([fixed in 1.15](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/6716723d9c8b8c87919a132fe3948709046a93d0))

The ReactJS tutorial suggests to [configure the Chrome Debugger](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/reactjs-tutorial#_configure-the-chrome-debugger) and display errors only in the Debug Console:

[image: https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/docs/nodejs/reactjs/hit-breakpoint.png]

Comment: This issue is over three years old. It was closed over two years ago. I doubt this is the case, I'm using an up-to-date VS Code.

Comment: I understand, which is why I added the second part of the answer, about the debugging console.

Comment: Chrome debugger is configured properly.  It doesn't solve the issue. I can see all the errors in the terminal window, anyway, but I'm looking for something more convenient than that. I really don't want to use Webstorm again...